# Properties of determinants and row operations

Tags: linear-algebra

As I understand it adding a multiple of a row to another doesn't effect the matrix, switching a row flips a sign, and multiplying a multiple increases the determinant the same amount.

Knowing that I have the matrix

```
[2  5  4  1]
[4  7  6  2]
[6 -2 -4  0]
[6  7  7  0]
```

I divide the row 3 by 2 to get

```
[2  5  4  1]
[4  7  6  2]
[3 -1 -2  0]
[6  7  7  0]
```

I then do the following operations

```
[2  5  4  1]
[4  7  6  2] + (-2 * row1)
[3 -1 -2  0] + (-3/2 row1)
[6  7  7  0] + (-3 * row1)
```

to get

```
[2  5    4   1   ]
[0 -3   -2   0   ]
[0 -8.5 -8  -1.5 ] * 2 
[0 -8   -5  -3   ] + (-2 * row2)
```

So the det will now be det(B) = 0.5 * det(A)

```
[2  5    4    1   ]
[0 -3   -2    0   ]
[0 -17  -16  -3   ] + (-5 * row2)
[0 -2   -1   -3   ]
```

Which gives me

```
[2  5    4    1   ]
[0 -3   -2    0   ]
[0 -2   -6   -3   ]
[0 -2   -1   -3   ] + (-1 * row3)

[2  5    4    1   ]
[0 -3   -2    0   ]
[0 -2   -6   -3   ] + (-2/3 * row2)
[0  0    5    0   ]


[2  5    4      1   ]
[0 -3   -2      0   ]
[0  0   -14/3  -3   ]
[0  0    5      0   ] + (-15/14 row3)

[2  5    4      1     ]
[0 -3   -2      0     ]
[0  0   -14/3  -3     ]
[0  0    0      45/14 ]
```

A triangular matrix det is the product of the main diagonal

```
 = 2 * -3 * (-14/3) * (45/14)
 = -6 * -(45/3)
 = -6 * -15
 = 90
```

Then I divide by 2 sense I multiplied a row by 2 and I get

45

I then multiply by the 2 I originally took out of row 3 to get

90 which is wrong.

However my calculator gives the answer as -90

Comment: Very last operation: "$+\ (\color{maroon}+15/24$ row3)", not "$+\ (\color{maroon}-15/14$ row 3)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the *last* row operation you performed, you added $\;\left(-\frac {15}{14}\right)\cdot \text{row 3}$ to each corresponding entry in the fourth row, which would give you a value of $10$ in the third entry of that bottom-most row, not $0$, as you indicate.

If you want to clear the entry $5$ in that last row, then you need to multiply row 3 by $\left(+\frac{15}{14}\right)$ and add to row4. Doing so will give you a determinant of $-90$, as desired.

Comment: Wouldn't it be +15/14 not +15/4 ?

Comment: Yikes, yes, sorry for the typo! You did a nice job, otherwise.

Comment: No problem thank you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice to help the OP +1